# How to render a IWICBitmap on screen of XAML UI and code behind in C++?

Tags: c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro, imaging

I am writing a Metro style app for Windows 8 in C++. In that, I am creating a IWICBitmap instance from an image file in my code. I will process the pixels myself on this IWICBitmap.

Now how do I display this image on a XAML element like a rectangle? A code snippet will be very helpful.

Comment: Why do you want it to be an IWicBitmap?

Comment: Actually I want to use Direct2D to draw stuff on the bitmap, which is easy with a IWICBitmap. I could use a WriteableBitmap to do pixels level processing and display it on the screen easily, but WriteableBitmap does not seem allow drawing using Direct2D. Lets say I want to add some text on the image?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this...

1. Create a WriteableBitmap of the same size.
2. Get the pixel buffer pointer from IWICBitmap.
3. Copy the pixels from IWICBitmap to the WriteableBitmap.

You need to take care of the pixel format though. And every time you modify something in the IWICBitmap, you will have to copy the content to the WriteableBitmap. I guess SurfaceImage would be a better thing to use.